# SVG + css3 animation not working with link markup

Tags: css, svg, css-animations

**Hi folks!**

I've been reading the awesome article **"Using SVG"** from Chris Coyer (http://css-tricks.com/using-svg/), and decided to use some things to make an animated logo. But I'ts been a little fight. I'll explain.

I'm using an **.svg** file for the logo. I'm pulling the file in an html file using the `<object>` tag. Inside the SVG file, I'm using **css3 animations** to do some tricks with the objects inside the svg.

Using the svg file with css3 animations and the `<object>` tag is working good. But the problem starts when I try to put this inside a `<a>` tag. I'm using a trick pointed at the Johan Hernández' comment on the article (I don't know the origin of the trick), and **exemplified in this fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/WEbGd/.

The problem is, with that, the link works, but not the css3 animations inside the SVG. I know it's because the `z-index` trick... but I didn't found yet a better aproach for this.

Maybe somebody have a suggestion to make this work, or at least for another approach? I made a Pen to help understand what I'm doing: http://codepen.io/seraphzz/pen/CJrBp.

**Here's the svg code that I made for test purposes:**

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px" width="176.5px" height="63.9px" viewBox="0 0 176.5 63.9" enable-background="new 0 0 176.5 63.9" xml:space="preserve" id="logo-svg">
<style>
    .style3{
        fill:   #9F4400;
    }
    .style4{
        fill:   #9331D3;
    }
    
    #logo-svg, #one{
        -webkit-transform-origin: center center;
           -moz-transform-origin: center center;
             -o-transform-origin: center center;
            -ms-transform-origin: center center;
                transform-origin: center center;
        -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
           -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
             -o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
            -ms-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
                transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    }
    
    #logo-svg{
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
           -moz-transform: scale(0.9);
             -o-transform: scale(0.9);
            -ms-transform: scale(0.9);
                transform: scale(0.9);
    }
    
    #logo-svg:hover{
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
           -moz-transform: scale(1);
             -o-transform: scale(1);
            -ms-transform: scale(1);
                transform: scale(1);    
    }
    
    #one{
        -webkit-animation: one .3s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-animation-play-state: paused
        -moz-animation: one .3s ease-in-out;
        -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
        -o-animation: one .3s ease-in-out;
        -o-animation-play-state: paused;
    }
    
    /*.active class added for test purposes*/
    #logo-svg:hover #one, #one.active{
        -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
        -moz-animation-play-state: running;
        -o-animation-play-state: running;
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes one{
        0%,50%,100%{-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
        25%,75%{-webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);}
    }
    @-moz-keyframes one{
        0%,50%,100%{-moz-transform: rotate(0deg);}
        25%,75%{-moz-transform: rotate(10deg);}
    }
    @-o-keyframes one{
        0%,50%,100%{-o-transform: rotate(0deg);}
        25%,75%{-o-transform: rotate(10deg);}
    }
    
</style>
<rect id="one" width="63.9" height="63.9" class="style3"/>
<ellipse cx="127.8" cy="34.5" rx="48.8" ry="12.8" class="style4"/>
</svg>
```

Any help would be very welcome!

Thanks!

### Edit:

After some research, I didn't found a possible and clean solution for this with only css3 and html5. So I'm giving a shot with a bit of javascript. I've made a fork of the previous pen with some javascript, here's what I'm getting until now: http://codepen.io/seraphzz/pen/lxKAw

What I'm trying to do is access the inner DOM of the SVG with Javascript. I'm having a problem accessing the content with `.contentDocument` on Chrome, witch may be caused by the file origin policy (the Chrome debug is returning this error: `Blocked a frame with origin "http://s.codepen.io" from accessing a frame with origin "http://favolla.com.br". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.`.

My idea here is access an element inside the SVG file with some id, and then, with javascript, change the class of the element with `.addClass`, for example. The class added is inside the .svg file (edited above).

What do you guys think about this approach?

Comment: I don't think `a` tags can contain `object` tags.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110113/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element "Content model:
Transparent, but there must be no interactive content descendant."  `object` tags are interactive content.  It's probably a fluke of WebKit that it doesn't move the object tag out from under the a tag... You might have to try something where you put it adjacent to your `a` tag, maybe z-index the anchor over the object, and try a:hover+object as selectors or something.

Comment: @JayC thanks for the sugestion and the solid information about the `<a>` tag! I'll look into that, if I have any progress I'll post here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This **can** be done using pure CSS3 and HTML5. The trick is to embed the link *inside* the svg by using the xlink element with the target set to parent:

```
<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <a xlink:href="../index.html" target="_parent">
        <rect id="one" width="63.9" height="63.9" class="style3"/>
        <ellipse cx="127.8" cy="34.5" rx="48.8" ry="12.8" class="style4"/>
    </a>
</svg>
```

The two important bits:

1. The `xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"` namespace.
2. The actual link: `<a xlink:href="../index.html" target="_parent"> </a>`

Note: This method has only been tested using the `<object>` method of embedding the SVG.

Comment: Awesome, @Caleb! This is just what I was looking for. I think that it fits my needs, cause I'm using the `<object>` tag to embed the svg, just like you said. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome @Diego, glad I could help! I just found this out the other day because I was trying to do the same thing that you are and Google didn't offer any help.

Comment: Seems to work via direct embedding too (no <object>).

Comment: I couldn’t get this to work on my thing in Safari but the sibling approach shown here worked: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22595572/1481076