# SVG css3 transition on fill not working when there is external link

Tags: css, html, svg, transition

I have a problem similar to this one : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16846628/svg-css3-animation-not-working-with-link-markup).

Only difference is that the page I want to link the SVG to is an external page meaning : http://www.google.ca

Currently in my code, changing the link to an internal page makes the css3 transition work but having it link to an external (http://) overrides the css3 transition I made.

If anyone has a workaround this issue or has dealt with this before. Please help!

Thanks!

```
    code
```

EDIT:
Forgot!
[JFIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/eEfjS/)

Comment: Can you possibly make a jsFiddle for this?

Comment: Strangely enough even when I link it internally the fade just works for the first click (target="_blank") then the link reverts to a normal hover without transition.

Comment: Sry! Added JsFiddle link! Thanks

Comment: This works perfectly on the latest Google Chrome...

Comment: I am on the latest Chrome. It works for the FIRST click only for me. Afterwards, the transition is abrupt. :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is actually something to do with the visited state. The reason the other commenters are saying it works is because they haven't been to your pages before. Once they have it will no longer work. I've tried adding visited states in the CSS and it makes no difference.

The easiest solution I've found is to just add a random query string to the url so the page is effectively not visited eg:

`<a href="http:/mysite.com/?foo=<?php echo rand(0, 99999) ?>">My Link</a>`

Most sites will ignore a query they don't recognise so that should be ok. Or better would be to remove it with JS on click.

```
$('body').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).prop('href');
    window.location.href = url.split("?")[0];
});
```

Comment: If only we could find a non-hacky workaround for this… or if only the webkit team would jump on it!

Comment: But the more I think about it the more I think this is a genius workaround! (I used current time – hour, minute, second, day, month – as my “random query string”.)

Comment: Thanks @JoelFarris ! This seems to be fixed in Chrome now btw.

Comment: Yes, I only see it in Safari now.

Comment: Update! This bug (which still occurs in at least Safari and IE 11) doesn’t seem to occur if you use 'currentColor' as the SVG’s fill!

Example: http://codepen.io/jifarris/pen/RREapp

I’ll add as an answer below.

Answer (score 4):

The bug still exists in at least Safari and IE 11 as of this writing but using `currentColor` for the SVG’s fill seems to fix it!

http://codepen.io/jifarris/pen/RREapp

```
<svg><path fill="currentColor"/></svg>
```

Comment: Amazing! Thanks @Joel

Answer (score 3):

I am a bit late with this answer, but just in case it might help others who end up on this page, this issue appears to result from a [know Chrome bug (101245)](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=101245). Basically, the transition stops working once the link is visited.

Therefore, to fix this issue, assuming you don't want to wait for the bug to be fixed, you will need to use a strategy that tricks the browser into thinking the link has not been visited.

Comment: It's actually [103354](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=103354) and seems to marked as closed since 2012... Regression I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the anchor into a div and appended a data attribute to it which contains the URL:

```html
<div id="homeLink" data-url="http://www.homelink.com">
  <svg id="SVG" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 838.95 520"></svg>
</div>
```

Than I added some JavaScript to get the URL and to append it to the location object:

```js
document.getElementById("homeLink").addEventListener('click',function(){
    var url = this.getAttribute('data-url');
    window.location.href = url;
},false);
```