# How to Nullify An Event Handler/Listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, anchor

Hey JavaScript people…

Is there a way to nullify a event listener I can’t find?

Long story short, I’m pretty sure there’s something in a WordPress theme I'm using ([Responsive](https://wordpress.org/themes/responsive)) that’s prepending my siteURL to EVERY anchor tag I place in header.php and I don't know how to stop it.

[Take a look at my site and source code for proof](http://brandonmoner.me/)

If someone would be so kind as to either inform me of a jQuery function to kill off anything the theme developer may have placed into there, or even find where it is in their code so I can remove it from my child theme I'd be grateful.

This issue has stumped quite a few people in other forums with no results, so I thought I'd try here. This is a free theme in the WP Repository that claims to be so customizable...yet I can't add any kind of link into the header file with it prepending my siteURL on it???

Comment: My site isn't down, I have it country restricted. Too many tricky people out there these days.

Comment: has nothing to do with theme or javascript. Disable javascript for page and results are the same. You need to learn what `relative path` means.

Comment: I know the difference between relative and absolute paths. However what you see on the front end is very different from what is in the backend. Don't believe me? Download the theme and try it. I'm sure you're right about it not being javascript, but something is making every link in there prepend my site url. I don't think I deserved a down vote for stating my problem.

Comment: Viewing the source code I'm not seeing anything prepended. Hovering over the links shows URLs exactly as I would except them to be, relative to the page itself.

Comment: @chris

What I'm saying is that they shouldn't be relative to the page itself. Maybe I'm explaining this wrong so I'm going to take another shot. SVG graphics don't like to be inside of an anchor with http prepended onto it when it comes to fill transitions. So I removed the php function and typed the absolute url without the http. However there's something going on in the header that prepends the site URL to all anchor tags within it. I could put an anchor tag with a link to Google.com, and when you hover over it the URL would read "brandonmoner.me/google.com". That's not supposed to happen.

Comment: You had it there for a bit, you had the href="`http://google.com` but now the links are back to just `href="google.com"`. Per the spec, failure to specify a protocol means that links are relative to the page.

Comment: Yeah I know. Although I was asking you about getting rid of the http, this whole thing in actuality had to do with SVG graphics. Check out this post a ran across AFTER scratching my head like crazy on this subject: http://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/svg-fill-transitions/

Comment: See this post, basically it has to do with the visited state overriding your expected state. http://stackoverflow.com/q/19500903/231316

Comment: @chris now THAT is an interesting read for sure. Nibbling on this knowledge. brb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is just a lost cause. I know that any text in the href without a protocol is assumed to be a relative path if there is no / or protocol. However I was hoping for a way around this as SVG fill transition animations have a bug in Chrome and Safari where they don't transition if they are inside of a hyperlink with http prepended onto it. They just turn on and turn of.

I'll just go with the 100% CSS route. This is too much of a headache.