# Why Doesn't This CSS Transition Work On SVG Inside an Anchor

Tags: css, svg, hover, anchor, transition

I'm trying to transition the fill and path of an embedded SVG object, however this doesn't seem to work (Code Pen [here](http://codepen.io/Pedr/pen/vyfko/)):

**The SVG:**

```
<a class="simple-link svg-link" href="">
  Some Text
  <svg version="1.1" id="next-page-icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
      viewBox="0 0 25 25" enable-background="new 0 0 25 25" xml:space="preserve" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
    <circle class="the-background" cx="12.5" cy="12.5" r="12.5"/>
    <g>
      <path class="the-icon"  d="M16.088,11.421l-3.404,3.362l-3.418-3.362v-1.204l3.418,3.444l3.404-3.444V11.421z"/>
     </g>
  </svg>
</a>
```

**The Sass:**

```
a
{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  overflow: hidden;

  @include transition(color, 1s);
  @include transition(background, 1s);

  svg
  {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;

    .the-background
    {
      @include transition(fill, 1s);
      fill: grey;
    }

    .the-icon
    {
      @include transition(fill, 2.5s);
    }
  }

  &:hover
  {
    color: red;
    background: black;
    .the-background
    {
      fill: black;
    }

    .the-icon
    {
      fill: red;
    } 

  }
}
```

**Why don't the fills animate on hover?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason why the transition doesn't work is because it is within a link.

To fix it, put the link inside of the SVG instead [like this SO post suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16846628/svg-css3-animation-not-working-with-link-markup)

OR

Make the SVG a sibling of the link and use the sibling selector

```
/* This goes within `a { ...` */
&:hover + svg { /* Or use ~ to select all */
  .the-background
  {
    fill: black;
  }

  .the-icon
  {
    fill: red;
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you! Worked in Safari, unlike other things I tried.

Answer (score 16):

The way I solved this problem was to place `fill="currentColor"` on the svg path element that I wanted to transition. Then I added `color` and `transition` properties to the surrounding anchor tag and performed the CSS transition on the anchor tag instead of the svg path itself. Below is a very stripped down example:

HTML:

```
<a>
    <svg>
        <path fill="currentColor" />
    </svg>
</a>
```

SCSS:

```
a { color: black; transition: color .2s linear;
    &:hover { color: white; } }
```

Answer (score 6):

I just discovered that in order to transition an svg fill within an anchor element, it only works using rgba color codes.  I haven't researched why that is, but it's working on my projects - here's an example: http://rawesome.leveragenewagemedia.com/ (hover the social media icons).

Here's the SASS I'm using:

```
.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  fill: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  -webkit-transition: fill .5s;
  -moz-transition: fill .5s;
  -ms-transition: fill .5s;
  -o-transition: fill .5s;
  transition: fill .5s;

  &:hover {
    fill: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  }
}
```

Comment: I just tried this and it appears it only works for opacity. Using different colors still won't transition with this method.

Comment: This solution definitely works for transitioning between color states. Thanks for posting this!

Answer (score 0):

I have to contradict the marked answer because, at least at this point in time, **the statement, svg transitioning and animating wouldn't work inside an anchor tag is simply not true.**

Working example:

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
        <body>
            <a>
                <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 800 600" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" style="fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:1.5;">
                    <path d="M211.281,336.939C211.281,336.939 285.671,363.039 355.793,360.727C425.915,358.414 439.329,333.635 491.159,336.939C491.159,336.939 494.646,428.533 356.402,433.741C219.839,438.885 216.224,360.378 211.281,336.939Z" style="stroke:#000;stroke-width:46.14px;"/>
                    <path d="M244.207,187.195C259.451,224.852 289.939,244.499 311.28,197.019" style="fill:none;stroke:#000;stroke-width:46.14px;"/>
                    <path d="M383.841,219.954C406.402,233.327 447.866,257.844 461.89,198.78" style="fill:none;stroke:#000;stroke-width:46.14px;"/>
                </svg>
            </a>
        </body>
        <style>
        
            svg>path{
                transition: 1s;
            }
            svg path:nth-of-type(1){
                fill:#ffe7cb;
            }
            svg:hover>path:nth-of-type(1){
                d: path("M211.89,300C211.89,300 286.281,348.171 356.402,343.902C426.524,339.634 439.939,293.902 491.768,300C491.768,300 495.256,469.047 357.012,478.659C220.449,488.153 216.834,343.258 211.89,300Z");
                fill:white;
            }
            svg:hover>path:nth-of-type(2){
                d: path("M244.207,187.195C259.451,173.171 289.939,165.854 311.28,183.537");
            }
            svg:hover>path:nth-of-type(3){
                d: path("M383.841,187.195C406.402,179.878 447.866,166.463 461.89,198.78");
            }
            a{
                height: 300px;
                width: 400px;
                display: block;
            }
        </style>
    </html>
```