# <a> link breaks SVG path transition in Safari

Tags: html, css, svg, hyperlink, safari

I have a normal SVG Triangle like this:

```
<svg width="200px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 200 200" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <polygon id="triangle"  fill="#000000" points="100 0 200 200 0 200 "></polygon>
</svg>
```

I'm using CSS to smoothly transition the color of the SVG when someone hovers over it:

```
#triangle { transition: 1s; }

svg:hover #triangle { fill: orange; }
```

This works in all browsers.

But now I want to add clickable link functionality to the same SVG,
so I surround it with link tags:

```
<a href="http://google.com">
  <svg width="200px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 200 200" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <polygon id="triangle"  fill="#000000" points="100 0 200 200 0 200 "></polygon>
  </svg>
</a>
```

BUT NOW in Safari my smooth color transition breaks. Instead of my original one second color transition, my SVG path now instantaneously changes color.

This does not happen in Firefox or Chrome.

Is this a glitch within Safari?

Here is my problem in [Codepen](http://codepen.io/TimArt/pen/lgLEp) http://codepen.io/TimArt/pen/lgLEp

Comment: Yes, when you wrap an inline SVG in an anchor tag, transitions break. This is a documented bug in webkit browsers, and maybe others. I have experienced it in several projects already. One way to get around this is wrap it in a <span> and use JS to fake an href action

Comment: Here is a related thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16846628/svg-css3-animation-not-working-with-link-markup but I haven't gotten the embedded link to work. Again, having JS hijack the click on the element is my best solution.

Comment: Those were the answers I needed, thanks!

Comment: Refer to my answer over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22593883/why-doesnt-this-css-transition-work-on-svg-inside-an-anchor/38597944#38597944

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I create a "fake-link" object in JS to use whenever this is the case. I can then attach '.fake-link' to any HTML element to replicate your standard `<a>` tag.

The JS:

```
/**
* Link namespace
*/
Link = function() {
};

/**
 * Fake a link
 */
 Link.prototype.openLink = function(el) {
    var link = $(el).attr('data-href');
    var win = null;
    win = window.open(link, '_self');
    win.focus();
};

window.Link = new Link();

$(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.fake-link', function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        window.Link.openLink($(this));
        return false;
    });
});
```

Some HTML:

```
<span class="fake-link" data-href="/about">
  <svg>
    INLINE SVG CONTENT HERE
  </svg>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `<a xmlns:xlink="" data-href="URL"` the transitions will work in safari/webkit browsers. You will still need  javascript to make the link work however. So for jQuery use this code also:

```
 $('#Element').click(function(e) {      
    location.href =  $(this).attr('data-href');
    e.preventDefault();

})
```