# CSS fill not transitioning for SVG wrapped in a tag

Tags: html, css, svg, webkit, transition

I am experiencing some very strange behavior, when wrapping an inline SVG in an `a` tag and then trying to transition the SVG's `fill` property on hover.

When the `a` tag's `href` is linked to a website, the transition is not working. However when it is linked to a `mailto:<>` the transition is indeed working. See the following example.

Why is the transition not working for the first `a` tag?

I saw another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25984517/3272409) where this was solved using some JavaScript hacking. I don't want to use JavaScript for this simple site I am building. Also the question is from 2014, if it is seriously a bug in webkit it can't be true that they haven't fixed it, right?

**NOTE:** I am using Safari 15.2 on macOS.

```css
.hover-div {
    fill: black;
    transition: all;
    transition-duration: 500ms;
}
.hover-div:hover {
    fill: deeppink;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <a href="https://stackoverflow.com">
        <svg class="hover-div">
            <use xlink:href="#rect"/>
        </svg>
    </a>
    <a href="mailto:contact@stackoverflow.com">
        <svg class="hover-div">
            <use xlink:href="#rect"/>
        </svg>
    </a>
</div>

<svg style="visibility: hidden">
    <symbol width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill-rule="evenodd" id="rect">
        <circle id="Oval" cx="50" cy="50" r="50"></circle>
    </symbol>
</svg>
```

Comment: Both examples are transitioning for me in Chrome 96 on Windows 10 Pro. Which browser are you experiencing this issue in?

Comment: Oh forgot that, I am using Safari 15 on macOS.

Comment: Alright, yes, I also see the first example failing to transition in Safari 15 on macOS 12.1 (Monterey).

Comment: Here's another duplicate with better answers for you: [Why Doesn't This CSS Transition Work On SVG Inside an Anchor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22593883/why-doesnt-this-css-transition-work-on-svg-inside-an-anchor).

Comment: @DM Perfect solution, thank you very much!